# Remove all underlines from links on a page?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have been noodling with a very simple CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

If I include this in the head of a page, it remove most of the underlines from links on a page.  But there are always some that persist.  For example, in gmail, there are underlines under 'About These Links', which is a span, 'Disable Buzz', also a span.

I have tried text-decoration: none on span and everything else I can think of but these underlines persist.

How can I get rid of these things?  Are there other elements that may have underlines?  How may I get rid of all of them?

Comment: Is there any sample web page you can provide that you have made and the hyperlinks won't go away ?

Comment: What does Gmail have to do with your code? But anyway, things can have a bottom border to appear that they have an underline as well. You also might have to add `text-decoration: none !important;` to force removal of the underline if it's being overriden by another style.

Comment: Perhaps these styles have !important after them over-riding that what you've set. As others have said, use firebug or developer tools in ie/chrome :)

Answer (score 2):

Without having seen the pages you have trouble with the best I can offer is this advice: use Firebug or a similar web developer tool to inspect the problematic elements to discover which CSS rules affect them and by analyzing these rules you can create your "counter CSS".

Comment: So the example I provided is in Gmail, everybody should have that. But I found the problem- my CSS is in the head of the page, whereas the elements I want to target are div's or span's with a style set on them.  Is there a way to set all child element text-decorations from the head and have it override their local styles?

Comment: Again, until you show the exact HTML and CSS you have, we can only give you suboptimal answers. CSS rules sometimes can become insanely complex when someone who is not familiar with such CSS concepts as "cascading" or "specificity" tries to rape it. You should google for "CSS specificity war" for enlightenment. So please, show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because links are broken up into several pseudo states that might be overwriting the style. Try this:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:visited:hover {
    /* :visited:hover is an old IE bug, not sure if it's still relevant */
    text-decoration:none;
}
```